# Sharing Ubuntu folders over a linksys router

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-share

I have two ubuntu computers and a linksys router.

How can I make them share **folders** between them?

Clarification (09/06/26):

- I have two ubuntu computers
- No Windows at all.
- They both share the same linksys router.
- One's IP is 192.168.1.101.  The other's is 192.168.1.103

How can I mount folders from one computer in another in Nautilus, just like I can in Windows Explorer?

Comment: I am using DropBox in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Should be all you need....

https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/internet/C/networking-shares.html

Comment: I'm trying what it says, but no luck.  Note:  This seems to explain how setup for use in a Windows network(SMB).  I have no windows at home.

Answer (score 1):

If both computers are connected to the same side of the router then the router has nothing to do with it.  What you need to do is NFS mount the folders from one computer to the other.

Comment: ok, how do I NFS mount?

Comment: This http://www.ubuntugeek.com/nfs-server-and-client-configuration-in-ubuntu.html article should give you what you need.  I don't know Ubuntu well enough to give you a command by command walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Samba if you want to use the SMB protocol. vsFTPd if you want to use the File Transfer Protocol. TFTP if you want to use something that is ancient and has no checksum. There are many many ways if you have them networked together. I would setup static IP addresses on them as to make it more permanent and for better access if name resolution fails, which it will if they are dynamically assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Unison: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

8.04 has a graphical Unison configuration tool that's fairly intuitive

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is [SSHfs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) Install SSH on the computers, use a secure password or keypair, and presto, encrypted transfer of files over port 22.